# Why do the dormitories in Yu-Gi-Oh GX have a hierarchy if the Egyptian god cards they are based on do not?

Tags: yu-gi-oh, yu-gi-oh-gx

In *[Yu-Gi-Oh! GX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_GX)*, the sequel series to *Yu-Gi-Oh!*, there are three dormitories that students live in at Duel Academy. They also have a clear hierarchy:

- Obelisk Blue

  - Named after "Obelisk the Tormentor"
  - Requires excellent test scores
  - Dormitories are incredible
- Ra Yellow

  - Named after "The Winged Dragon of Ra"
  - Requires adequate test scores
  - Dormitories are well-kept
- Slifer Red

  - Named after "Slifer the Sky Dragon"
  - Allows anyone with even poor test scores
  - "It's like an outhouse with a deck" according to Syrus

However, the three Egyptian God Cards that the dorms are named after do not have any sort of hierarchy; they are all equals.

So why do these dorms have a hierarchy? Did Kaiba (founder of the Duel Academy) just want to make his original god card the best dorm and snub Yugi by making his original god card the worst dorm?

Comment: I will be honest. "Because Kaiba made those rankings" was the first reply that came to my mind, too.

Answer (score 3):

It's because Kaiba created the school and Slifer was Yugi's god card, so he made it the lowest dorm. Obelisk was Kaiba's god card, so he made it the best dorm.

Answer (score 2):

The gods have a hierarchy. They are depicted in a pyramid like structure with ra at the top and osiris and obelisk at the bottom.
Ra stays at the top  as a hierarchy 2 god while obelisk and osiris stay as equals hierarchy 1 gods at the bottom. Not only do their special abilities are useless against ra but they also cannot target ra for an attack.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of this hierarchy? Did it ever appear in either the manga or TV show?